# Prevent Autofac from registering all types in referenced assemblies

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm using autofac modules to register my applications services/types etc... like so:

```
 var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
 builder.RegisterModule(new ConduitRegistryModule());
 // etc...
```

Example module class/code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Handle the container builder load event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="builder">The builder through which components can be registered.</param>
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        RegisterServices(builder);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Register conduit services.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="builder">The builder through which components can be registered.</param>
    private void RegisterServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<Conduit>().As<IConduit>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<PhonelistService>().As<IPhonelistService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<UtilityService>().As<IUtilityService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<VacancyService>().As<IVacancyService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<InteractionService>().As<IInteractionService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
```

This is then being built in the `Global.asax.cs` file on application start where `Get()` returns the builder with registered modules:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilderFactory().Get();

_containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(builder.Build());
```

This is all great however I'm finding that a lot of unrelated types are being registered by autofac when i review containers component registery property. This is causing some issues with some types that are part of a framework we use (have no control over these unfortunately) so would like to configure Autofac to either:

a) NOT register all types/classes in the application (I thought using autofac modules would achieve this?)

b) Exclude a specific type/class/interface from registration

Are either of these possible? Have I possibly used modules incorrectly somehow? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Autofac` won't register types by itself (except some internals things). What are theses registered types you don't want to be registered ? Could the framework register it ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand - Upon closer inspection it appears to be related to `Autofac.WebForms` automatic property injection. In my particular case its trying to inject into some properties that the framework classes/controls define, seems like I can use `AttributedInjectionModule` instead of `PropertyInjectionModule` and then manually marking each of the classes where property injection is required with `InjectPropertiesAttribute` though this is a lot of reworking.... is there a better/easier way to do this?

Comment: The `PropertyInjectionModule` will resolve any settable property of the current handler. It should not register anything. Are you using `AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource` ? This module will automatically register anything and it may be the main issue